# "docker container run" requires at least 1 argument

Tags: mysql, docker, containers, volume

I'm trying to create a container using a volume that I have already created, but my console shows the error

`docker container run" requires at least 1 argument`

This is the command I'm trying to run:

```
docker container run --name db -v volume-dados-do-banco:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mypass
```

I have also tried this one, wih more arguments, but the same error persists:

```
docker container run -d --name db -p 3306:3306 -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mypass -v volume-dados-do-banco:/var/lib/mysql
```

Any thoughts on the reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just restarted docker and ran:

```
docker run --name torgmysqldb --volumes-from volume-dados-banco-mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mypass -p 3307:3306 mysql
```

I found out a known issue about this:
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2722

Comment: This known issue is not the problem you had, in your case it is just a misuse of docker run command. Restarting docker is not what helped there, adding image name (`mysql`) at the end did the trick.

Answer (score 7):

Problem is not with docker, you just didn't specify which image to run. Your command should include Docker image as per [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/).

> docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE[:TAG|@DIGEST] [COMMAND] [ARG...]

Example would be:

```sh
docker run -d --name db -v volume-dados-do-banco:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mypass mysql:latest
```

Answer (score 4):

i just had the same problem with psql my password simply contained & and i needed to escape it with / before &

Comment: I think it must be a back slash \ instead of forward slash /

Comment: Duuude! Thanks man, you just saved me hours! You're my hero of the day!
@umer, you too! :)

Answer (score 0):

try the below command.. it seems a syntax error on your command..

```
docker container run -d --name db -v volume-dados-do-banco:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Mypass
```

Comment: ok. can you please run just from normal volume rather then the sql thing..   
      docker container run -d --name db -v volume-dados-do-banco:/var/lib/mysql

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem when i use this:

```
docker run  -d -p 3306:3306 -v /Volumes/wd4black/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql
```

but when i try below, the problem is disappear:

```
docker run --name my-s -d -p 3306:3306 -v /Volumes/wd4black/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql
```

so i think the --name is key, but the doc didn/t write it.

Answer (score 0):

After you have extracted the image from the Docker repository, you can move on to deploying the new Container with the following code snippet:

```
sudo docker run --name=[container_name] -d [image_tag_name]
```